# Spring Boot + Spring Security Oauth2 failure handler not getting called

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

My goal is to have a spring boot application host my react application as well as provide backend apis. The react app is hosted at / and all my apis I place with a url prefix of /api. Right now when I am unauthorized and hit /api/* I get a 200 back with the OKTA login form as the body.  I would like for this to be a 4xx response instead.  I only want the OKTA login form when I try to hit / and am unauthorized.  I tried adding a failure handler but it is not getting called.  Below is my web security config:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .oauth2Login()
                .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**/*.{js,html,css}").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/", "/api/user").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Comment: Does an unauthorized request return a 200, or are you getting 302'd a few times and end up a login page (with a 200 status)?

Comment: I would suggest splitting your code into 2 applications. Your `"/api/**"` endpoints seem to belong on an *OAuth2 resource server* and not on an *OAuth2 client*. If your application is a resource server, you will get the desired 4xx response when the user is unauthorized. You can see more about the configuration here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2resourceserver